# Remove Radio Buttons on Step 1 of Magento Onepage Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

I'm looking remove the "Continue" button on step 1 of Magento Onepage Checkout. I've tried the code at [Thinking Magento](https://www.creativemgroup.com/creative-media-web-services/magento-blog/24-magento-remove-the-ugly-radio-buttons-from-checkout) with no luck.

Rather than a radio button, I'd like the option to be a button itself. Once clicked, the user is moved onto step 2 based on their selection.

Here is the current code in onepage:

```
<?php if( $this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout() ): ?>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <?php if( $this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout() ): ?>
            <li class="control">
                <input type="radio" name="checkout_method" id="login:guest" value="guest"<?php if($this->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod()==Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_GUEST): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" /><label for="login:guest"><?php echo $this->__('Checkout as Guest') ?></label>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <li class="control">
                <input type="radio" name="checkout_method" id="login:register" value="register"<?php if($this->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod()==Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_REGISTER || !$this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif ?> class="radio" /><label for="login:register"><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></label>
            </li>
        </ul>

    <?php else: ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="checkout_method" id="login:register" value="register" checked="checked" />
    <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required">&nbsp;</p>

        <?php if ($this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout()): ?>
            <button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button" onclick="checkout.setMethod();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
        <?php elseif ($this->helper('checkout')->isCustomerMustBeLogged()): ?>
            <button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/url')->getRegistrationUrl();?>'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></span></span></button>
        <?php else: ?>
            <button type="button" class="button" onclick="checkout.setMethod();"><span><span><?php echo ($this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout() ? $this->__('Continue') : $this->__('Register')) ?></span></span></button>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

And there's the setmethod js:

```
    setMethod: function(){
    if ($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) {
        this.method = 'guest';
        var request = new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveMethodUrl,
            {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'guest'}}
        );
        Element.hide('register-customer-password');
        this.gotoSection('billing', true);
    }
    else if($('login:register') && ($('login:register').checked || $('login:register').type == 'hidden')) {
        this.method = 'register';
        var request = new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveMethodUrl,
            {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'register'}}
        );
        Element.show('register-customer-password');
        this.gotoSection('billing', true);
    }
    else{
        alert(Translator.translate('Please choose to register or to checkout as a guest').stripTags());
        return false;
    }
    document.body.fire('login:setMethod', {method : this.method});
},
```

Curious if anyone has a more updated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple, you will just need to change below code in your checkout login.phtml file.

Find the code below

```
<ul class="form-list">
    <?php if( $this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout() ): ?>
    <li class="control">
        <input type="radio" name="checkout_method" id="login:guest" value="guest"<?php if($this->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod()==Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_GUEST): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" /><label for="login:guest"><?php echo $this->__('Checkout as Guest') ?></label>
    </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li class="control">
        <input type="radio" name="checkout_method" id="login:register" value="register"<?php if($this->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod()==Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_REGISTER || !$this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif ?> class="radio" /><label for="login:register"><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and change it to

```
<ul class="form-list">
    <?php if( $this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout() ): ?>
    <li class="control">
        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="$('login:guest').checked = true;checkout.setMethod();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout as Guest') ?></span></span></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="checkout_method" id="login:guest" value="guest"<?php if($this->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod()==Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_GUEST): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
    </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li class="control">
        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="$('login:register').checked = true;checkout.setMethod();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></span></span></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="checkout_method" id="login:register" value="register"<?php if($this->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod()==Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_REGISTER || !$this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif ?> class="radio" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can remove your continue button from this file.